# Parse XML with namespace in RootElement in PHP

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, simplexml

I have the following XML file with namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dc:languages xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:lang name="C">
        <dc:appeared>1972</dc:appeared>
        <dc:creator>Dennis Ritchie</dc:creator>
    </dc:lang>
    <dc:lang name="PHP">
        <dc:appeared>1995</dc:appeared>
        <dc:creator>Rasmus Lerdorf</dc:creator>
    </dc:lang>
    <dc:lang name="Java">
        <dc:appeared>1995</dc:appeared>
        <dc:creator>James Gosling</dc:creator>
    </dc:lang>
</dc:languages>
```

I want read the creator value, but my code not working.

```
$languages = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
$ns = $languages->getNamespaces(true);

$parent = $languages->$ns["lang"];

foreach($parent as $lang) {
    $dc = $lang->children($ns["dc"]);
    echo $dc->creator.'<br>';
}
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `SimpleXMLElement::getNamespaces()` to fetch the namespace URIs from the document. They are the defining values, not the prefixes. Prefixes/Aliases are optional for XML element nodes and can change at any element node. So just define an array for all the namespaces you're using.

`SimpleXMLElement::children()` acts like a filter and returns a `SimpleXMLElement`. You can use the property syntax to access the filtered child elements.

```
$languages = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$ns = [
  'dc' => 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'
];

$parent = $languages->children($ns["dc"])->lang;    
foreach($parent as $lang) {
    $creator = $lang->children($ns["dc"])->creator;
    echo htmlspecialchars($creator).'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
Dennis Ritchie<br>Rasmus Lerdorf<br>James Gosling<br>
```

In DOM you can use Xpath (after registering the namespaces) to fetch the values:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('d', 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');

foreach($xpath->evaluate('/d:languages/d:lang') as $lang) {
    $creator = $xpath->evaluate('string(d:creator)', $lang);
    echo htmlspecialchars($creator), '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I'm always suspicious of my over simple looking answers.

Answer (score 1):

Despite really good answer from ThW, this also seems to work....

```
<?php


$xml= simplexml_load_string(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <dc:languages version = "2" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
         <dc:lang name="C">
             <dc:appeared>1972</dc:appeared>
             <dc:creator>Dennis Ritchie</dc:creator>
         </dc:lang>
         <dc:lang name="PHP">
             <dc:appeared>1995</dc:appeared>
             <dc:creator>Rasmus Lerdorf</dc:creator>
         </dc:lang>
         <dc:lang name="Java">
             <dc:appeared>1995</dc:appeared>
             <dc:creator>James Gosling</dc:creator>
         </dc:lang>
     </dc:languages>'
);


foreach($xml->xpath('//dc:lang') as $lang) {
    echo $lang->xpath('dc:creator')[0]."<br>";
}
```

and produces this output from a CLI.

```
Dennis Ritchie<br>Rasmus Lerdorf<br>James Gosling<br>
```

However I did have to modify your XML a tad or simplexml_load_string() would return error.

```
<dc:languages xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
```

to

```
<dc:languages version = "2" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
```

Comment: LibXML has an broken feature that registers the namespace definitions of the current context. You can use Xpath with SimpleXML, but you should register the namespaces on each SimpleXMLElement instance you call the method `xpath()` on.